# Update/add a single value to an array in MongoDB - but not as list?

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to simply add one value to a tuple from MongoDB.
The key is `query`, and the variable `position` should be added as `consumer`-Variable in the tuple with the following code:

```java
MongoCollection<Document> collection = ...
Bson filter = Filters.eq("query", queryName);
Bson update = Updates.addToSet("consumer", position);
collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update);
```

However, when I look into my database, it looks like a **list `"consumer" : [ NumberLong(88760) ]` has been inserted** and **not a single value**, as shown in the `producer` field:

```java
{ "_id" : ObjectId(...), "query" : "1000", "consumer" : [ NumberLong(88760) ], "producer" : NumberLong(88760) }
```

I also tried `Update.push()` with the same result.
**How can I add just a single value, without having it as list?**

Comment: `.set()` rather than `.addToSet()`

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you need to update only 1 object from the list inside, you can do it in the format as:

```
.update_one({"_id": ObjectId(_id)}, {"$set": {"i.5": list[2]}})
```

where `"i.5"` - `5` index of the list `i`.